# Creating custom list click counter in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am experimenting with kivy and wrote a list click counter in kivy. When button is pressed it should show the list element as well as the number and the next click should show the next list element,number this is repeated till the list is completed. This is my python file.

```
#main.py
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App


class Page(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SimpleKivyApp(App):

    def onClick(self,i,j):
        ls=["foo","boo","goo","koo","bar" ]         
        for i,j in enumerate(ls):    
            self.root.ids.id1.text=str(i)+" "+str(j)

    def build(self):     
        return Page()

a=SimpleKivyApp()
a.run()
```

kv file

```
#simplekivy.kv
<Page>:
    Label:
        id:id1
        pos:0,0
        font_size:80            

    Button:
        size_hint:0.5,0.2       
        font_size:60
        text:"Submit"
        on_press:  app.onClick()
```

I dont know the logical way to submit the key event for kivy. I tried looping through the list but I know its not the right way and it crashes.

Comment: Can you show the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

On every click, the list is reinitialised. Do something like:

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
class SimpleKivyPage(Page):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ls = ["foo","boo","goo","koo","bar" ]
        self.identify = ObjectProperty()


class SimpleKivyApp(App):
    page = SimpleKivyPage()

    def onClick(self,i,j):
        self.page.identify.text=str(i)+" "+str(self.ls[i])
        self.i += 1

    def build(self):
        return self.page

a=SimpleKivyApp()
a.run()
```

Also, modify your `kv` file:

```
#simplekivy.kv
<SimpleKivyPage>:
    identify: id1
    Label:
        id:id1
        pos:0,0
        font_size:80            

    Button:
        size_hint:0.5,0.2       
        font_size:60
        text:"Submit"
        on_press:  app.onClick()
```

Comment: thanks for the code but I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'SimpleKivyApp' object has no attribute 'built'`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
     a.run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 799, in run
     if not self.built:
 AttributeError: 'SimpleKivyApp' object has no attribute 'built'` this is the full error

Comment: it return this attribut errror `AttributeError: 'SimpleKivyApp' object has no attribute 'onClick'`

Comment: another error `ValueError: SimpleKivyPage.id accept only str`, shouldnt `self.id = ObjectProperty()` be `self.id1`

Comment: its become confusing can you post both the python and kv code

Comment: @EKa Here you go :) I've added more modifications.

Comment: Its not working for me `NameError: global name 'page' is not defined` have you tried it in your system

Comment: Its giving me `Fatal Error` now. I think click counter is not possible with kivy. For now I am abonding it and do it some other time .Thank you for taking your valuable  time for trying.